# Android - Playing MP4 video file from an expansion file

Tags: android

I have followed all the steps in testing an expansion file for my application. Where I am stuck now is how to play a video file contained in that expansion file.

I have successfully been able to download it from Google Play, and I can see it in the folder it is supposed to be in when I browse through my file manager.

I have looked for the past couple of days in trying to figure out how to play the file. At the moment there is only one for, to maintain appropriate size for testing.

I have tried to parse the URI and set it in the videoview, however, it always shows that the video cannot be played.

I have also tried this code so far to access it (as read in the documentation, and I have replaced the parameters with my parameters):

```
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a merger of both the main and patch files
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(appContext,
    mainVersion, patchVersion);

// Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file ZIPs
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

What do I do with the input stream in order to play the video?

Answer (score 1):

#### Code for provider

```
public class EHZipUriProvider extends APEZProvider {

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "your.package.name.Utility.EHZipUriProvider";
}
```

}

#### Custom video player

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri
        .parse("content://your.package.name.Utility.EHZipUriProvider");

public static VideoView mview;

public static void playVideo(Context context, VideoView resource, String VIDEO_NAME) {
    position = 0;
    mview = resource;
    Uri video = Uri.parse((CONTENT_URI + "/" + VIDEO_NAME));
    mview.setVideoURI(video);
    mview.start();

    mview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mview = null;
        }
    });
}
```

#### Calling in activity

```
VideoPlayer.playVideo(context, vv, "rulesofenglish.mp4");
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, my application package name is:

> com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp

Then my expansion file should be

> main.1.com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp.obb

In detail, you can follow in [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html):

> [main|patch].< expansion-version >.< package-name >.obb

---

From expansion you can get it via three ways:

*via AssetFileDescriptor*

```
// This one works with an image file and a media file.
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a specific expansion file
// mainContext, version number of your main expansion, version number of your patch
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this, 1, 0);
AssetFileDescriptor afd_img1 = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("your_path/your_file.jpg");
AssetFileDescriptor afd_mpbg = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("your_path/your_file.mp3");

// To set image
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(afd_iv1.getFileDescriptor()));

// To set sound
try {
    mpbg.setDataSource(afd_mpbg.getFileDescriptor(), afd_mpbg.getStartOffset(), afd_mpbg.getDeclaredLength());
    mpbg.prepareAsync();
    mpbg.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.w("Error=====", "Failed to prepare media player", e);
}
```

---

Via InputStream:

```
// This one works with an image file and a media file.
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a specific expansion file

ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(filePathToMyZip);

// Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file ZIPs

InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

---

#### Via Uri

```
// This one can use in almost thing such as jpg, mp3, mp4, pdf, etc.

// You need to create a new class to override APEZProvider
public class ZipFileContentProvider extends APEZProvider {
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp";
    }
}

// You need to add <provider> in AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
 android:name="com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp.ZipFileContentProvider"
   android:authorities="com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp"
      android:exported="false"
      android:multiprocess="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="mainVersion"
              android:value="1"></meta-data>
</provider>

// After that, you can use it any time by this code:
String filename2 = "image/i_commu_a_1_1_1_1.jpg"; // suppose you store put your file in directory in .obb
String uriString2 = "content://com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp" +  File.separator + filename2;
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriString2);
imageView2.setImageURI(uri2);

// Filename inside my expansion file
String filename = "video/v_do_1_1_1.mp4"; // Suppose you store put your file in directory in .obb
String uriString = "content://com.bw.sample_extension_download_main" +  File.separator + filename;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

v1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
v1.setVideoURI(uri);
v1.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a provider (the best solution for me)! I tested it, and it works perfectly.

See *[Android: read media file from .obb using APEZ](http://nullpointerexc.blogspot.fr/2014/05/android-read-media-file-from-obb-using.html)*.