# Access mp4 files from Android Expansion files

Tags: android, google-play, mp4, apk-expansion-files

Found  [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863169/android-playing-mp4-video-file-from-expansion-file) but no one seems to respond on this

I have been referring [this](http://blogmobile.itude.com/2012/11/22/expanding-your-horizons-using-expansion-files-for-android/) blog for my development. I was able to play mp4 videos without any trouble when they were in R.raw. When I moved them to the expansion files Im getting issues with the playing.

Can any one tell me what Im I missing here?

Logcat :

```
05-08 18:45:23.602: E/MediaPlayer(11452): prepareAsync called in state 1
05-08 18:45:23.602: W/dalvikvm(11452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0×41172390)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): java.lang.IllegalStateException
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepareAsync(Native Method)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(MediaPlayer.java:1283)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:239)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:197)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:187)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at rmm.android.app.VideoPlayerActivity.playVideo(VideoPlayerActivity.java:307)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at rmm.android.app.VideoPlayerActivity.onClick(VideoPlayerActivity.java:475)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
05-08 18:45:23.622: E/AndroidRuntime(11452): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
```

Thanks in advance

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the .obb file. After a lot of browsing and trials I found that actual reason for this **Exception**.

*What I was doing:*

1. Create a zip file by clicking the folder with videos (Via Compress
   option when you right click on the folder in Ubuntu)
2. Rename the .zip file to
   .obb
3. Push this obb file to
   mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/package_name_folder

*What I was supposed be do:*

1. Create the .obb file using the [Jobb tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html) from Android tool  (Android/tools/jobb)
2. Repeat the step 3
3. Done !

**Creating .obb file :** `$ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11`

And finally, use [ObbExpansionsManager](https://github.com/uncleLem/AndroidUtils/blob/master/src/ua/a5/androidutils/utils/ObbExpansionsManager.java) to access the files

Comment: Congratz dude you've made it @rahul

Comment: another way you could approach is zip the .mp4s but ask zip not to compress the mp4s. Command in terminal. zip -n .mp4 <zipfile> <filestozip> .. then the mp4's are not compressed and they play properly.